# Automatic generation of latex source

Tags: pythontex

I have a `python` script that reads a file containing data + some "latex template". The script produces a long latex source which is compiled to obtain a PDF.

Incidentally, the LaTeX source heavily relies on `PythonTex`. So I wonder if it might be possible to keep script, data, and template in the same latex file  (not at the cost of legibility of the source) and just run latex/pythontex.

It would have the following advantages:

1. everything would be kept in a single file;
2. the script and pythontex could run in the same python session and be aware of each other.

Below a simple (almost trivial) example of what the script does. Suppose the template/data file is

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
*** is *** years old\par
\end{document}
\begin{data}
Bob 88
Mik 76
\end{data}
```

The script produces

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Bob is 88 years old\par
Mik is 76 years old\par
\end{document}
```

**EDIT** For a less trivial example, imagine that the template is an arbitrary piece of latex/pythontex and that the data contains pieces of latex/pythontex code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: answer using pythontex**

I am sure that the answer to your to your question is yes but a "proper" answer is not really possible without more details about what you are trying because you are currently asking for a black box to produce a black box:).

This said, the following code shows one way of using [pythontex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pythontex) to correctly typeset your MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{pycode}
data = { 'Bob' : 88,
         'Mik' : 76
        }
\end{pycode}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
for person in data:
  print('%s is %s\n' % (person, data[person]))
\end{pycode}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

A few comments:

- As with python, indentation is really important: the initial indentation inside the`pycode` environments should be flush left and the following lines have to obey the usual python rules
- There are several other ways of injecting python code into the document. Depending on what your real application looks like, the `pycode` environment may not be the best approach. Consult the [pythontex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pythontex) manual for more details
- To compile, first run (pdf)latex, then pythontex and then (pdf)latex again
- I needed to install the pygments library to get this to work (for example, use `pip install pygments`).

**First suggestion using csvsimple**

Perhaps this does not suit your real application, but given your MWE I would suggest using [csvsimple](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple) rather than [pythontex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pythontex).

For example if your main tex file looks like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[head to column names, tabular=l]{data.csv}{}{\person\ is \age}

\end{document}
```

and `data.csv` contains

```
person,age
Bob,88
Mik,76
```

The output is the same as above.

As I said this may not fit your actual use-case, but personally I find [csvsimple](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple)  really useful for things like this. It is surprisingly powerful, well documented and easy to use. [This is not meant to be a sale pitch I have no stake in the package and do not know its author!]

Comment: My MWE is deceptively minimal. I have edited the question to explain the level of complexity of the real application.

Comment: @PrimoPetri OK, I've added a pythontex answer